# Find row, ten integer objects long, check if any of the integers is positive and output row number.[Python 3.x]

Tags: python

So I've been working on simple cycles and general purpose outputs/inputs in Python, not used to Python mind you, so there might be an easy solution to my problem and I just overlooked it and complicated it.

So I've created code for generating a user-defined long list with random integers from -100 to 100, and then it's printed in rows of 10 integers. I've created a function to count positive integers in said list, but now I want to add a way to determine which rows have at least 1 positive integer, and that's my problem, I can't figure it out, at all.

This is what I've currently created (the code just gets stuck on the function and never completes it, just gets stuck:

```
import random
import math
import itertools as it

def round_up(n, decimals=0):
    multiplier = 10**decimals
    return math.ceil(n * multiplier) / multiplier

def main():
    global L
    print("How many numbers would you like to create?")
    N = int(input(""))
    print("")
    print("")
    
    L = []

    for s in range(0, N):
        R = random.randint(-100, 100)
        L.append(R)

    for s in range(0, len(L), 10):
        print(*L[s:s+10])
        print("")
    
    return L

def positive_number_count():
    C = 0
    S = 0
    Len = len(L)-1
    
    while S<=Len:
        if L[S]>0:
            C=C+1
            S=S+1
        else:
            S=S+1
        if S>Len:
            break
    
    print(f'There are {C} positive numbers!')
    

def rows_with_positives():
    value=0
    while value<len(L):
        if L[value]>0:
            print(L[value])
            value=int(round_up(value, -1))
            if value>len(L):
                break
        if value>len(L):
            break
```

I haven't thought of other ways to look at it, although I did try the "for...in" cycle. neither did that work, so I am just confused at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify the `rows_with_positives` function. You can iterate over the list `L` in chunks of 10 elements and check if any one element in each chunk is positive. If so, you can print the row index or the elements in that row. Following is the modified function:

```py
def rows_with_positives():
    row_size = 10
    for i in range(0, len(L), row_size):
        row = L[i:i+row_size]
        if any(number > 0 for number in row):
            print(f"Row starting at index {i} contains at least one positive number.")
            print("Row contents:", row)
```

The above function uses the `any` function to check if there is any positive number in each row (basically, a chunk of 10 elements). If there is at least one, it prints the row index and the contents of the row. Otherwise, it prints nothing. The `range` function is just used to iterate over the list in steps of `row_size` (10 in this case).

Testing out the code:

I changed the `row_size` in the following to `3` for testing purposes.

```py
L = [-1, -2, -3, -10, 36, -4, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, -92]

def rows_with_positives():
    row_size = 3
    for i in range(0, len(L), row_size):
        row = L[i:i+row_size]
        if any(number > 0 for number in row):
            print(f"Row starting at index {i} contains at least one positive number.")
            print("Row contents:", row)

rows_with_positives()
```

Output:

```
Row starting at index 3 contains at least one positive number.
Row contents: [-10, 36, -4]
Row starting at index 6 contains at least one positive number.
Row contents: [40, 50, 60]
Row starting at index 9 contains at least one positive number.
Row contents: [70, 80, -92]
```